# Express JS and Discord JS Give role

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, discord.js

Evening,
I'm trying to give role to a user from a post method using the express framework. And i don't know how to do it because normally i would do it via the message function.

Here is the code

```
// Require the necessary discord.js classes
const { Client, Events, GatewayIntentBits,EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,] });

// When the client is ready, run this code (only once)
// We use 'c' for the event parameter to keep it separate from the already defined 'client'
client.once("ready", c => {
    console.log(`Ready! Logged in as ${c.user.tag}`);
    
});


client.login("");


const express = require("express"); 

const bodyParser = require("body-parser") 
const app = express(); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ 

    extended:true

})); 

  
  

app.post("/giverole", function(request, response) {
  if (request.body) {



  response.status(200);
    response.send({
      status: "success",
    });

  } else {
    response.status(404);
    response.send({ status: "error"});
  }

  return;
}); 

  

app.listen(6969, function(){ 

  console.log("server is running on port 6969"); 
})
```

I've tried caching the guild but when i try and give the role it gives a issue about it's not a function.

Comment: So what do you send in `request.body`?

Comment: Your POST request should include the Guild and GuildMember id. Fetch the guild, then fetch the member with said guild. Apply the role to the fetched member.

Answer (score 0):

You can access members in a guild by using `client.guilds.fetch('id')`, and then by fetching the members through that.

```
app.post("/giverole", async function(request, response) {
  if (request.body) {

  let guild = await client.guilds.fetch('GUILD-ID-HERE')
  let member = await guild.members.fetch('MEMBER-ID-HERE')
  await member.roles.add('ROLE-ID-HERE')

  response.status(200);
    response.send({
      status: "success",
    });

  } else {
    response.status(404);
    response.send({ status: "error"});
  }

  return;
});
```

`fetch()` returns a promise, so it's the cleanest if you make the function async like I did in the example.